# How to display overlapping images in a browsable list in Android

Tags: android

I intend to create an application that shows images that are in a vertical line (later the line can become a curve) but they can overlap. 
It means that images at the bottom of the list can be partially over the next image in line but their "distance" can be modified dynamically so the overlap can be gone if the distance is big enough.

I was thinking of what solution I should use.

1. I could use a ListActivity and create the row item layout for the images and set is orientation to vertical - it seems hard to customize
2. I could use some canvas drawing but then I have to calculate distances of centers of the images to create a line (curve) - it seems lots of extra work to make the layout okay

What else should I consider?